# Magento 2 CMS, pages, orders and customers grids

Tags: magento-2.1, ajax, php-7

Magento 2 latest version currently will not load any grid in the admin, there is no errors in the console whatsoever. The requests via Ajax are not even firing.

However I have installed my custom module which holds its own grid which works perfectly fine :( confused!

I've tried disabling/removing my module from the code and still doesn't work. I'm running out of options.

Hopefully someone can shed some light on the issue. I believe this is happening for a lot of people however none of there issues related to the same as mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your module uses `etc/adminhtml/di.xml` to add your data provider. This is a problem because magento uses `etc/di.xml` to declare it's data provider collection and it gets overriden by the more specific `adminhtml` collection.

You need to add your data provider in `etc/di.xml` instead.

Comment: If anyone is experiencing this issue then this is the problem, great work Aaron.